# How to disable Hibernate flooding logs

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, tomcat, jpa

Hibernate is flooding my IDE console with tons of unnecessary informations at every connection. I already read out the documentation and googled trying to solve this issue but till now the problem "persists".

My persistence.xml:

```
< persistence > 
...
< property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
< property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="false" />
< property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="false" />
...
```

My log4j.xml:

```
...
< logger name="org.hibernate" > 
    < level value="NONE" />
    < appender-ref ref="MY_LOG" />
    < appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
< /logger>
...
```

I have no other log4j configuration in my project and even in my environment. Anyone there figured out how to disable the Hibernate console logs? Maybe has something I didn´t understand?

I'm using Hibernate 3.5, Tomcat 6.0 and Eclipse 3.3.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if "NONE" is a valid level in log4j (maybe it is).  You could try changing the Level to "OFF" (or at least "WARN" or "ERROR").

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Level.html

Comment: In fact it makes no difference if i put DEBUG, INFO, FOO etc. The hibernate still flooding the IDE console. Thats is the point. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think Tomcat expects a log4j.**properties** file in `WEB-INF/classes`. Have you tried converting the .xml to that?

Comment: No, I din´t. I´ll going to do it now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Could also be the [Tomcat internal logger](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/logging.html#log4j), especially if it's logging connection info and select statements.

Comment: It really makes sense. But because the container is encapsulated as a runtime in the Eclipse environment I´m not so sure about the correct way to do it. So, I followed the instructions suggested to made the modifications and made them in the tomcat home directory, but without effects. In doubt, I created a new runtime and publish the project under it and still got floods in the console. Thank you anyway.